# React правильный render для такого уровня вложенности?

Tags: reactjs

Есть такая структура

-Main

--CatalogWrapper

---CatalogPoint

----CatalogItem

-Aside

При клике на компонент CatalogItem я должен сделать изменения в Aside, по сути добавить новую структуру. Верно ли я понял что писать логику в CatalogItem - ошибка
Требуется написать на уровне Main?

Comment: Скорее даже еще выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [контекст](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Оберните `Main` и `Aside` в общий контекст, получите структуру вида

```
<Context>
  <Main>
    <CatalogWrapper>
      <CatalogPoint>
        <CatalogItem />
      </CatalogPoint>
    </CatalogWrapper>
  </Main>
  <Aside />
</Context>
```

`Main`, `Aside`, `CatalogItem` свободно получают доступ к контексту.

Если контекст не хотите, то придется поднимать состояние до общего родителя `Main` и `Aside`